# Why does gofmt remove indented TODO formatting?

Tags: go, comments, todo

It seems gofmt in go1.19 changed its behavior to not allowing indenting based on some heuristics (from go docs: https://tip.golang.org/doc/comment). But this breaks the TODO comment formatting.

This is what I used to have in my code that gofmt accepted.

```
// TODO: Do some stuff. And this is a long comment so it'll need to
//       be wrapped. This is the next line.
```

Running gofmt gives me this:

```
// TODO: Do some stuff. And this is a long comment so it'll need to
//
//  be wrapped. This is the next line.
```

I could change it to this but then GoLand doesn't display the TODO properly.

```
// TODO: Do some stuff. And this is a long comment so it'll need to
// be wrapped. This is the next line.
```

[image: GoLand view]

Any ideas on how to reconcile these problems? I don't understand why the accepted style for TODO has changed.

Comment: From that link you provided, "In both of these, the last line is indented, making it a code block. The fix is to unindent the lines." Seems like Go thinks it shouldn't be indented. Maybe GoLand needs to change?

Answer (score 1):

The custom pattern I used to recognize `TODO` is

```
\/(\/|\*)[ ]*\btodo\b(.|\n)*(\*\/|)
```

[image]

---

Here are steps to set it in Goland

- In the Settings/Preferences dialog , select Editor | TODO.
- Use a regular expression to specify a custom pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a tab in front of your TODO, like this:
[image]

Comment: The key to this approach is that there must be an unindented comment above.  If the `Function is a function` line doesn't exist, then gofmt will remove the tab in front of the TODO and revert to the OP's problem.